# How do I schema bind a function that uses geography or Json in SSDT?

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I have a table valued function that I'd like to add to my ssdt project.

```sql
create function dbo.fn_get_n_geos(@p0 nvarchar(max),@n bigint)
returns table
with schemabinding as
return 
select top(@n) geo=geography::Point(latitude,longitude,4326)
              ,row=-1 + convert(int,row_number() over (order by (select 1)))
from openjson(@p0)
with (latitude float 'strict $[0]', longitude float 'strict $[1]');
```

When I add this function I get the following warnings::

> > SQL70561: Cannot schema bind function 'dbo.fn_get_n_geos' because name 'geography' is invalid for schema binding. Names must be in two-part format and an object cannot reference itself.
> >
> > SQL70561: Cannot schema bind function 'dbo.fn_get_n_geos' because name 'float' is invalid for schema binding. Names must be in two-part format and an object cannot reference itself.

When I execute this function in SQL management studio everything works correctly. How do I get SSDT to play ball with these features?

My project is targeting SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR: Try qualifying names with `sys.`

In your case, try changing `geography` to `sys.geography`; and you might also have to do the same with the `float` columns in your `OPENJSON` call, too.

---

Just came across exactly the same problem but with an `OPENJSON` with explicit `nvarchar` column mappings, e.g:

```
OPENJSON(@query) 
WITH
(
  axis nvarchar(64) '$.axis',
  value nvarchar(max) '$.value' AS JSON
)
```

I was getting the errors on the `axis` and `value` lines.

It appears to be a bug in SSDT - reported by `John.Nelson` on the Developer Community portal [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/858510/cannot-schema-bind-function-using-openjson-with-ex.html).

I was all-set to suggest the ugly fall back to post-deploy, and then I stumbled across [this over on Dba Stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24015/visual-studio-dac-with-schemabound-view-containing-hierarchyidgetroot-two) (I searched for the error code SQL70561) where the OP is getting the same error in a view that uses `hierarchyid`.

The solution there was to qualify `hierarchyid` to `sys.hierarchyid`.

I have ***never*** bothered qualifying built-in SQL type names - but, sure enough, once I changed my OPENJSON call to:

```
OPENJSON(@query) 
WITH
(
  axis sys.nvarchar(64) '$.axis',
  value sys.nvarchar(max) '$.value' AS JSON
)
```

*That* worked for me.

Comment: Inexplicably this worked. Noone would probably do this except to work around the bug.